# Update MariaDB table with variable from curl in bash script

Tags: bash, curl, mariadb

I have read literally every answer on the net that I could find. Nothing is similar to my problem, so here it is:

I have a bash script with curl and I get a variable back. I want to update my database with this variable, however it doesn't work.

My variable is $stream and no matter what I do, I always get the word `"$stream"` into the database instead of the result of the curl.

My script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
    
stream=$(curl --silent "https://player.mediaklikk.hu/playernew/player.php?video=mtv1live&noflash=yes&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&correlator=&osfamily=Windows&osversion=10&browsername=Chrome&browserversion=97.0.4692.99&title=M1&contentid=mtv1live&embedded=0" | grep -Po 'file": "\K(.*?)(?=")' | sed 's/\\\/\\\//https:\\\/\\\//g')
    
echo $stream

mysql
use mydatabase;

UPDATE my_table SET my_url = "$stream" WHERE my_name = 'stream_name';
```

Comment: I don't see how that's being used as input to `mysql` in the first place. You need to use `<<` to make it a here-document.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for reply. I am a beginner. I have no idea what you mean :-)
It took about ten hours for me to get that what you see. I looked up here documents, but I don't really understand how I should use it in this case. But thanks anyway.

Comment: [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678915/whats-the-difference-between-and-in-bash) and [this](https://ryancollins.org/2016/01/24/using-a-here-document-with-bash-and-mysql/) may help.

Comment: I don't understand how your script is doing anything at all if you don't use a here document. When it executes `mysql` it's going to wait for you to type commands, it won't treat the following lines as SQL commands.

Comment: @Barmar I don't know how it works, but it works. Don't ask me why. YOu are coding since 1979, you should know. :-P It writes to the database. It just writes the wrod "$stream" instead of the result.

Comment: It would do that if you typed those commands by hand, it shouldn't write anything to the DB if you run it as a script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-e` option to execute a query. Put this in double quotes and variables will be expanded.

```
#!/bin/bash

stream=$(curl --silent "https://player.mediaklikk.hu/playernew/player.php?video=mtv1live&noflash=yes&output=vast&unviewed_position_start=1&env=vp&impl=s&correlator=&osfamily=Windows&osversion=10&browsername=Chrome&browserversion=97.0.4692.99&title=M1&contentid=mtv1live&embedded=0" | grep -Po 'file": "\K(.*?)(?=")' | sed 's/\\\/\\\//https:\\\/\\\//g')

echo $stream

mysql mydatabase -e "UPDATE my_table SET my_url = '$stream' WHERE my_name = 'stream_name';"
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked!

Comment: From manpage for mysql command `--execute=statement, -e statement`